# Magento how to sort by new products first

Tags: magento

I try to use below code but this code give only new product and i need new product firs and then other prodct.

```
$todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()                   
                ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                    0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
                    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
                ), 'left')
                ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
```

Any one idea for that ??

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: try without 
"->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                        0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
                        1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
                    ), 'left')"
this line

Comment: Refer it. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/26662/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i get my one question answer :)

==================Set this code in your /Catalog/Product/List/Toolbar.php file=================

```
private function _getNewProducts() {
    $todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
    $collectionNew = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()                   
                ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                    0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
                    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
                ), 'left')
        ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc');
    return $collectionNew->getAllIds();
}

public function setCollection($collection) {
    $this->_collection = $collection;

    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

    // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
    $limit = (int) $this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'newest') {
        $this->_collection->getSelect()->order('FIElD(e.entity_id, ' . implode(',', $this->_getNewProducts()) .') DESC ');
    }

    return $this;
}


public function getAvailableOrders() {

    $this->_availableOrder = array(
        'newest' => $this->__('New Product'),
        'name' => $this->__('Name'),
        'price' => $this->__('Price')
    );
    return $this->_availableOrder;
}
```

This work perfect!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Install this extension 
[sort by date](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sort-by-date.html)

See the following step Define in Image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'status', 'eq'=>'1')))
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC');
```